# Exception about modifying collection

Tags: c#, exception, dictionary

I have the following code that iterates over a dictionary, and if the key doesn't have a value, it checks another dictionary for a value and assigns it. I keep getting the following exception though.

`-      $exception  {"Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute."} System.Exception {System.InvalidOperationException}`

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> param in request.Field.StoredProcedure.Parameters)
{
    if ((param.Value == null || param.Value.Length == 0) &&
         request.SearchParams.ContainsKey(param.Key))
    {
        request.Field.StoredProcedure.Parameters[param.Key] =
             request.SearchParams[param.Key];
    }
    else if (param.Value == null || param.Value.Length == 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(
            "No value could be found for sproc parameter " + param.Key);
    }
}
```

Are you not able to assign a value to a collection while you are iterating over it?

Comment: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.getenumerator.aspx): "An enumerator remains valid as long as the collection remains unchanged. If changes are made to the collection, such as adding, modifying, or deleting elements, the enumerator is irrecoverably invalidated and its behavior is undefined."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use an enumerator after you modify the collection it's looking at, as it might leave the enumerator in an invalid state.  You should be able to grab a copy of the contents with `.ToArray()` and then modify the `KeyValuePair`s stored in that:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> param in request.Field.StoredProcedure.Parameters.ToArray())
{
    if ((param.Value == null || param.Value.Length == 0) && request.SearchParams.ContainsKey(param.Key))
    {
        request.Field.StoredProcedure.Parameters[param.Key] = request.SearchParams[param.Key];
    }
    else if (param.Value == null || param.Value.Length == 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("No value could be found for sproc parameter " + param.Key);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

> Are you not able to assign a value to a collection while you are iterating over it?

Correct. Try this instead:

```
foreach (var param in request.Field.StoredProcedure.Parameters.ToList())
{
    ...
```

This is because `foreach` uses an Enumerator, and ..

> An enumerator remains valid as long as the collection remains unchanged. If changes are made to the collection, such as adding, modifying, or deleting elements, the enumerator is irrecoverably invalidated and its behavior is undefined.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.getenumerator.aspx

If you add a `.ToList()`, you are now enumerating a copy of the collection, and you can modify the original without affecting the copy.

Answer (score 2):

> Are you not able to assign a value to a collection while you are iterating over it?

That's exactly the case.  You can't change the collection while iterating through it with `foreach`.